# How does Spring Social use HandlerInterceptorAdapter redirect to Facebook login page?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, interceptor, spring-social

I use the quickstart project from [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples) to start learning spring-social.
This project use a class `UserInterceptor` which extends `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` to interceptor all servlet requests. If the user is not already authenticated, the user will be redirected to login page. There is a button of a social provider. for example Facebook. It is a form with POST and a hidden field which contain authorization scope which this website needed. After user click this, the user will be redirected to social login page.

But I couldn't find where this POST request is being handle. There is no controller method mapped to this POST request. I tried to set a breakpoint on every method of `UserInterceptor`, still do not figure out how this is done.

There is also a related question. If I use interceptor to check if the user is authenticated. How do I handle requests that doesn't need authentication?

P.S. I used to use spring security to do authentication and page security. Not getting how this could be fused with spring social.